# keyword analysis: to return rows for which a description column contain one or more words that are in another column in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table (Table A) with a description field (varchar(max)).
I have another table (Table B) with a field With keywords.

For all rows in table B I want to return all the rows from Table A that contain at least one occurence of the keyword specified in table A.

I have googled and searched on this site but haven't found any example how to do this. All the examples I have found are require you to input the search string instead of just running the query dynamically.

Comment: Simply do a `JOIN`.

Comment: Using some kind of 'Like'-statement? Table A contain between 1 and 200 words while table B contain only one word or phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcards and a join like this:

```
declare @TableA table (description varchar(max))
declare @TableB table (keyword varchar(max))

insert into @TableA values ('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.'), ('I think, therefore I am.')
insert into @TableB values ('jumped'), ('therefore'), ('fox'), ('th')

select * from @TableB b
inner join @TableA a on a.description like '%' + b.keyword + '%'
```

Results:

```
keyword       description
jumped        The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
therefore     I think, therefore I am.
fox           The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
th            The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
th            I think, therefore I am.
```

Comment: "_at least one occurence_", i.e. `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TableB
JOIN TableA ON tableA.description LIKE '%' + TableB.keyword + '%'
```

I would recommend you put a full text index on description field and use it's searching capabilities as doing that `LIKE` search with wildcards on both sides won't be able to use any normal indices.  This also assumes one keyword per row in TableB.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    Id INT Identity Primary Key,
    Description varchar(max)
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    Id Int Identity Primary Key,
    Keyword Varchar(max) 
)


INSERT INTO TableB (Keyword)
VALUES ('My'), ('Ipso'), ('Dipso'), ('Dinosaur')

INSERT INTO TableA(Description)
VALUES ('My very best friend'), ('Ipso Ipso Dipso'), ('My favourite Dinosaur is a T_Rex'),('None of the above')


SELECT *
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
    ON Description LIKE '%' + Keyword + '%'
```